# Can't insert multiple rows in SQL Server Manager Express 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a Table **HORAS_X** with `ID_HORA(int), ID_ZONA(int), DESCRIPCION(nvarchar), COMIDA(bit), META(int), NUMERO(int)`.

I can insert a single row like:

```
INSERT INTO HORA_X 
   (ID_HORA,ID_ZONA,DESCRIPCION,COMIDA,META,NUMERO) 
VALUES
   (2,2,'06:00-07:00',0,174,1);
```

And it works.

However when I try to insert multiple rows like this:

```
INSERT INTO HORA_X 
   (ID_HORA,ID_ZONA,DESCRIPCION,COMIDA,META,NUMERO) 
VALUES 
   (3,3,'06:00-07:00',0,174,1),
   (4,4,'06:00-07:00',0,174,1);
```

It throws the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Wrong syntax near ','.`

Is my Syntax wrong? I checked online and it's supposed to be fine.
And yes, I have restarted SQL Server Manager, thanks for any lead and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly, SQL Server 2005 does not support `VALUES` table value constructor. It was introduced in SQL Server 2008, so for SQL Server 2005 you need to use the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO HORA_X (ID_HORA,ID_ZONA,DESCRIPCION,COMIDA,META,NUMERO) VALUES (3,3,'06:00-07:00',0,174,1)
INSERT INTO HORA_X (ID_HORA,ID_ZONA,DESCRIPCION,COMIDA,META,NUMERO) VALUES (4,4,'06:00-07:00',0,174,1);
```

Notes: SQL Server Manager Express 2005 is a tool, but I assume, that you are using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: You are right. My bad...
I guess the examples I read were from SQL 2008 and up.